# Jfrog Xray behind Reverse Proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, jfrog-xray

I tried to put our xray behind a reverse proxy and want to configure a location path so that under /xray my xray can be found and under /artifactory my artifactory. Can the path specified somewhere in the xray_config.yaml?

Answer (score 0):

You should configure the Xray [Base URL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/XRAY/Configuring+Xray) through which Xray will be accessed.
To configure the base URL go to Admin > General Settings > Base Settings.